# Terraform AWS - route table association - add multiple subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have created 4 subnets in my vpc, 2 of them public and 2 of them private.
I need to associate 2 public subnets to a one route table and 2 private subnets to another route table.
Looking at the docs, `aws_route_table_association` seems like accepts only one `subnet_id`.

How do I add multiple `subnets` as show in this pic?

[image]

## Associate route table to subnets

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-test" {
  subnet_id =                                         -> I need to add 2 public subnets here
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public-test.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-test" {
  subnet_id =                                          -> I need to add 2 private subnets here
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private-test.id
}
```

Here are the subnets and routes:

## Create Subnet

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public-test-a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/28"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = var.AZ[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test-a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-test-b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.16/28"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = var.AZ[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test-b"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-test-a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.32/28"
  availability_zone = var.AZ[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "private-test-a"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "private-test-b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.48/28"
  availability_zone = var.AZ[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "private-test-b"
  }
}
```

## Create route table

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public-test" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/26"
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id =aws_internet_gateway.myIG-test-02.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private-test" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/26"
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.myNat-test-02.id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simple declare two route table association resources.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_test_a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/28"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = var.AZ[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test-a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-test-b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.16/28"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = var.AZ[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test-b"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-test-a" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public-test-a.id # first subnet
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public-test.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-test-b" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public-test-b.id # second subnet
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public-test.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public-test" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc-test-02.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/26"
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id =aws_internet_gateway.myIG-test-02.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public-test"
  }
}
```

Also it is considered good practice to follow naming conventions. Quoting the [docs](https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/naming)

> Use _ (underscore) instead of - (dash) in all: resource names, data source names, variable names, outputs.
> Beware that actual cloud resources have many hidden restrictions in their naming conventions. Some cannot contain dashes, some must be camel cased. These conventions refer to Terraform names themselves.
> Only use lowercase letters and numbers.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. Can you also answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819338/terraform-loops

Comment: No worries, the question has already been answered by someone else the right way